# equal to operator == can be used to do checking bit ?

Tags: c++, c, operators, bit-manipulation, equality

What is the purpose of the function ?

```
 bool whatIsIt(double n)
 {
    return n == n;
 }
```

It can be used to check every bit in n ?

I doubt that .

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the standard does not say. It depends on how floating point math operates on your platform.

Comment: I would have said it checked that n is a number vs NaN for example

Comment: The technical term for this kind of boolean function is "a tautology" ;)  BTW: "Not a Number" is a legal IEEE floating point value ... and it is NOT equal to any other floating point value - including itself.

Comment: @TonyLee: That assumes that the concept of NaN exists on the target architecture, and that the compiler is not set to optimize such code out.

Comment: @paulsm4 : Generally true, but floating-point types are "special", so it's not true in this case.

Comment: @ildjarn: floating-point types *may* be special. They may be not.

Comment: @Billy : And that fact alone makes them always special, no? ;-]

Comment: I'm willing to bet this function actually has a useful name.

Comment: @ildjarn: Erm, no. It depends entirely on the architecture. If your architecture doesn't support things like NaNs, then this function will always be true. If your compiler optimizes it out, it will always be true. If your platform is set to throw floating point exceptions on NaN comparisons, then the function won't even finish executing. But it's all compiler/platform/machine dependent. Your platform might treat things specially (most do), but no standard says it must.

Comment: @Billy : I know what you meant. :-] What I meant is that because so many aspects of floating-point math are implementation defined, floating-point types are always "special" in the sense that the code alone is not enough to demonstrate a probable motivation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It could be used to check if n is NaN (not a number), since NaN does not compare equal to itself.

Probably a finnicky and not entirely reliable way to do it. (see Billy's various comments)  C99 and C++11 have the `isnan()` function.

Comment: +1 -- emphasis on "could" -- we don't know for sure. Depends on the architecture/platform/settings/compiler/etc.

Comment: C99 also has `isnan()` (presumably where C++11 has inherited it from).

Answer (score 4):

This is specified in the C Standard in Annex F: 60559 Floating Point Arithmetic, specifically F.8.3 Relational operators:

> ... The statement `x != x` is true if `x` is a `NaN`
>
> ... The statement `x == x` is false if `x` is a `NaN`

If `__STDC_IEC_559__` is `#defined`, then this function will return false if `n` is `NaN`.

Comment: +1 -- for C99 anyway. At least of the TC3 draft I was able to get my hands on

Answer (score 2):

It's probably there to detect NaNs (which are never equal to anything, even each other) -- though that's going to depend on your particular compiler/platform/settings/etc. The standard, strictly speaking, does not say how floating point math is handled.

Comment: but C does specify how `NaN`s are handled relationally, assuming the implementation #defines `__STDC_IEC_559__`.

Comment: @MSN: That's only C99. The question says C and C++, which usually means "C++ and the C subset" -- neither of which specify any kind of `__STDC_IEC_559__`. (Had the question been tagged "C" or "C99" of course that would have been different....)

Comment: @MSN: Though, to be fair, I have not yet been able to get my hands on a copy of the C++11 standard, because ANSI has not gotten off it's butt and I don't want to pay $300 for a standard ANSI sells for $18.... (And besides, if the constant is not defined, then anything is fair game)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not "checking bits".

I'm guessing that it IS checking for "NaN'.  It will return FALSE if the input is NaN, and return TRUE if it's any other floating point value.

Answer (score 0):

That function checks that a number is comparable.

This can be very important for values used as a key to  a sort function or used in a search.  The compare used in a sort expects that if A < B is true, then B < A will be false.  If A or B were an uncomparable value, both those statements would be false.

Technically what sort requires is called [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering).

An element in a collection that has an uncomparable value can't be found.  A list that contains an uncomparable value is unsortable.  Further, an optimized implementation may walk out of the array being sorted and start corrupting memory or may never terminate.

The only non-comparable value I know of for a double is NaN. As others have pointed out, NaN will return false if used as a parameter to `whatIsIt()`.  If NaN is a possible value  for numbers you compare, then you have to handle it or bad things may happen.

Issues with std::map and NaN are mentioned in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28C++%29) wikipedia article.

You can construct a compare to sort NaN to a given spot in a list, but you can't do it with just the built in operators.  Instead you'd do something like

```
if ( A < B ) then return -1;
else if ( B < A ) then return 1;
else return whatIsIt(A) - whatIsIt(B);
```

As an aside, in SQL, NULL also can't be compared in compliant implementations.

The mystery in this is why isnan() wasn't used unless this was an interview question or something.